# How to notice the other peer that the call is ended?

Tags: android, sip

I'm developping a SIP application and I'm facing a problem: When I end a call in a peer, the call is not ended in the other one. How can I solve this problem ? Can I add something to the function onCallEnded?:

```
    public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
      updateStatus("Call ended.");
    }
```

Or is there any other solution?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking way too much info for a real answer.  You should generate a tcpdump/wireshark trace and see a) if the BYE is sent, b) if it goes to the correct address (the SIP server you both registered with normally), c) if the other end receives the BYE, which it should if it's properly built *and* the other end doesn't have issues with a router closing the incoming SIP port, and d) if the 200 OK to the BYE gets back to the sender.  Note that if you use the wrong routing options on the INVITE the BYE will try to go directly to the other phone, and not to the SIP server.  This is usually not a good thing.